# How can I debug Django ORM/SQL issues? (fresh migration gives null value error, existing db has broken data)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

So, in a bit more detail I have a model with a field like: `permalink = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

I've not actually been using this field - but would now like to.

However, it seems all models on this table, `permalink` is now `57295730` - on all 2000 models!

In an attempt to debug, I tried completly wiping the DB, running `migrate` (~100 migrations) - but then creating a instance of the model, I am told `permalink violates the not-null constraint` though I am definitely passing it a value! I also get a *list* of the values I am passing it, but am not sure how to know which value/column relates to which field?

I've even tried removing DB, removing migrations, running a new `makemigrations` - and still get the null violation...

even stranger, it looks like this field has not been touched since the initial migration!

`migrations$ egrep permalink *
0001_initial.py:                    ('permalink', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
migrations$`

I'm running (k)ubuntu `14.04`, postgres `9.3`, python `3.4`, django `1.9.4`

Though I'd love to know how to fix this - my question is really "What can I do to debug this kind of situation?"

Comment: Also - cannot edit the value of `permalink` admin says it has changed, but it remains unchanged. All other data _looks_ OK and _seems_ to edit OK too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Not the answer I want - but a working answer:

1. do automated testing
2. use CI! Prevent this problem in the first place

And if you are not doing the above...
 use `git bisect` (or if you cant, manually use `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to find the problem!)

in mycase, I was over-riding the save function of the model in a... stupid way!

edit:
in a little more detail, I was setting `permalink` to be 1 greater than the current biggest value - but in an earlier commit, had removed the + 1

However, I did not notice this error quickly, as it did not happen with data in the DB.

So! the error was actually quite informative - had I been running my tests more often (or using CI) I would have been informed of the error instantly, and saved myself quite a headache!

so, in short: **write tests, run them - *automatically* **